# How to definitely set mouse speed/acceleration independently of mouse version and type on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, mouse

the problem is that the speed and acceleration of my mouse is too high and the system setting (Ubuntu) is completely useless so I need an external tool/trick to adjust it.

So, how to slow down definitely the mouse at startup without doing the command manually?

The `xinput list`'s output is:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYN1B7E:01 06CB:2970 UNKNOWN              id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CHICONY USB Keyboard                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Now, at startup I setted this command:
`xinput --set-prop "pointer:MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse" "libinput Accel Speed" -0.7`
but with appareantly no reason, at some time the mouse come back to its initial speed value...

Also, sometimes at startup the command does not work.

My aim is simple to have a mouse with always the same acceptable speed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To set the speed, use this:

```
xinput --set-prop device_id_or_name "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" number
```

In your case:

```
xinput --set-prop "MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" -0.7
```

Save the above in a file as ~/.xprofile.

Comment: The second example doesn't work. See my question, there is already that command.

What the command `~/.xprofile` do?

Comment: Save the command in a properties file for the xinput: ~/.xprofile; and NOT as startup command in a script.

Comment: This solution implies that if I change the mouse, I'll need to manually modify the file. Can you suggest a persistent and mouse-type independent solution?

Comment: I would not recommend to set up such a command for a number of devices. The basic dpi setting of different mice are not the same, and if you modify them in general, they will have not the same speed.

Comment: I asked for a definitive solution. How to set the mouse speed in relation of the pixel movement of the cursor?

Comment: It is not possible. Different mice have different built in configuration for dpi. You can override it with xinput and put into the config of xinput and autostart by startup. But if you use another deveice, it will not work. In linux you do not have a general device called mouse. In your case, you have 'MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse', and if you connect another mouse, the settings for the new device will set to default. It is a totally new device, your system has never seen it, and so on, it can not configure it.

Comment: Sure it is possible... Simply you do not know the solution.

Comment: I used your code but at startup sometimes I still need to run it manually because it seems that that command runs too early...

Answer (score 0):

Use [THIS](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubo77/mouse-speed/master/usr/bin/mouse-speed) script. It will do all the hard work for you.

https://github.com/rubo77/mouse-speed

Alternatively you could run something like `xset mouse 10 0`

Or you could create an Xorg config `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/acceleration.conf`

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Mouse"
    MatchIsPointer "yes"
# set the following to 1 1 0 respectively to disable acceleration.
    Option "AccelerationNumerator" "2"
    Option "AccelerationDenominator" "1"
    Option "AccelerationThreshold" "4"
EndSection
```

Comment: The script solution enforce me to run the script at every login and every time the system change the mouse speed for some reason.`xset mouse 10 0` isn't a definitive solution. The `Xorg` way does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The following settings is working fine in my linux.

First get the pointer id using following command:

```
$ xinput --list
```

Then replace $id with pointer id

```
$ xinput set-prop $id 'libinput Accel Speed' 0.65
$ xinput set-prop $id 'libinput Accel Profiles Available' 1, 1
$ xinput set-prop $id 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' 1, 0
$ xinput set-prop $id 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 0.3125, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 1.16
$ xset mouse 15/1 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bash script to do the hard work for you, and then call it automatically via udev rules every time the mouse gets connected to any USB port.

**1st STEP) Get the idVendor and idProduct from your mouse** 
1. Connect the mouse to any usb port 
2. Launch the terminal and execute the command below to list the details of your usb devices

```
lsusb
```

You'll get an output similar to this

```
Bus 001 Device 074: ID 1038:1300 SteelSeries ApS
```

After "ID" and before ":" is the idVendor. 
After ":" and before the name of the mouse is the idProduct.

**2nd STEP) Create a bash script (fixMouse.sh) to do the hard work for us** 
1. Launch the terminal and execute the command below to create and edit a file named fixMouse.sh under /usr/local/bin/

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/fixMouse.sh
```

2. Insert the following code and save the file

> ```
> MOUSE_ID=$(xinput --list --short | grep MOSART | cut -d "=" -f2 | cut -c 1-2)
> if [ ! -z "$MOUSE_ID" ]
> then
>   PROP_ID=$(xinput --list-props "$MOUSE_ID" | grep 'Accel Speed' | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -c 1-3 | tail -2 | head -1)
> fi
> if [ ! -z "$MOUSE_ID" ]
> then
>   xinput --set-prop "$MOUSE_ID" "$PROP_ID" -1
> fi
> ```

**3rd STEP) Create a .rules file under /etc/udev/rules.d** 
1. Launch the terminal and execute the command below to create a mouse.rules file

```
nano /etc/udev/rules.d/mouse.rules
```

2. Insert the code below, changing the values accordingly, and save the file.

```
> ACTION=="bind", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0.0",
> ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/<your-user-name>/.Xauthority",
> ATTRS{idVendor}=="<your-mouse-idVendor>",
> ATTRS{idProduct}=="<your-mouse-idProduct>",
> RUN+="/usr/local/bin/fixMouse.sh"
```

**4th STEP) Making the changes permanent for debian based distros with Gnome** 
*(for other DMs please take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321)* 
1. Launch the terminal and execute the command below to go to the autostart folder

```
cd ~/.config/autostart
```

**Note:** If that doesn't work, create the directory with the following command

```
mkdir ~/.config/autostart && cd ~/.config/autostart
```

2. Execute the command below to create a file named fixMouse.desktop

```
nano fixMouse.desktop
```

3. Add the following content

> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Type=Application
> Exec=/usr/local/bin/fixMouse.sh
> X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
> NoDisplay=false
> Hidden=false
> Name[en_US]=fixMouse
> Comment[en_US]=fixes Mouse sensitivity issue after startup
> X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=0
> ```
>
> 4. Execute the following command to give execution permission to fixMouse.desktop

```
chmod +x fixMouse.desktop
```

**5th STEP) Reboot your system** 
 
**Note:** I was able to reproduce the 4th STEP on a Debian distro with Cinnamon, without any errors.

Comment: Does this method work also if the mouse is always inserted before the boot?

Comment: Hi @user2342558, you can achieve this - on Ubuntu - with the following tutorial https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/. I'll add another STEP for this purpose.